# placing 50% transparent div over canvas so canvas is still visible

Tags: css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am having trouble placing a `div` over a `canvas` where the `canvas` is still visible. I can only get it to where the `div` is over the `canvas` but the `canvas` is hidden. If anyone has an example that would be lovely.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = screen.width;
canvas.height = screen.height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var tau = 2 * Math.PI;

function Triangle(canvs, cnt, sid, f) {
  this.phase = 0;
  this.ctx = canvs.getContext('2d');
  this.first = f;
  this.sides = sid;
  this.canv = canvs;
  this.draw = drawTriangle;
  this.size = 100;
}

function drawTriangle() {
  requestAnimationFrame(drawTriangle.bind(this));
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var centerX = this.canv.width / 2;
  var centerY = this.canv.height / 4;
  this.phase += 0.005 * tau;

  if (this.first == 1) {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canv.width, this.canv.height);
  }
  this.ctx.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0; i <= this.sides; i++) {
    this.ctx[i ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](
      centerX + this.size * Math.cos(this.phase + i / this.sides * tau),
      centerY + this.size * Math.sin(this.phase + i / this.sides * tau)
    );
  }
  this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#dda36b';
  this.ctx.stroke();
  this.size--;
}

var collection = [];

var triangle1 = new Triangle(canvas, context, 3, 1);
triangle1.draw();

var i = 0;

function nextFrame() {
  if (i < 1000) {
    collection[i] = new Triangle(canvas, context, 3, 0);
    collection[i].draw();
    i++;
    setTimeout(nextFrame, 500);
  }
}
setTimeout(nextFrame, 0);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #19191b
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <button id="test">Test button that needed some text to make it longer</button>
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

So the button takes up the entire width of the screen and you cannot see anything beneath it. I would like the div to be transparent so you can see the triangles beneath it.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: **Use CSS**: Create a container div with `position:relative`. Put both your canvas and test div in the container with `position:absolute`.  Give the test div `opacity:0.50`

Comment: @markE You should make a proper answer out of this comment.

Comment: @Philipp. We're moving so I have less time for full answers. Thank you, though, for posting an answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`position:absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fposition) so you can freely position elements in their parent element with `top` or `bottom` and `left` or `right`. This allows HTML elements to overlap. Make sure that those elements you want to be in the foreground come after those you want to be in the background (or alternatively, use the [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) CSS property).

This is your code slightly modified for faster results. I did not change anything of matter in the JS section (just removed the resizing code so the demonstrated behavior is visible sooner). Interesting are the changes to the CSS and HTML below.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('.mycanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var tau = 2 * Math.PI;

function Triangle(canvs, cnt, sid, f) {
  this.phase = 0;
  this.ctx = canvs.getContext('2d');
  this.first = f;
  this.sides = sid;
  this.canv = canvs;
  this.draw = drawTriangle;
  this.size = 100;
}

function drawTriangle() {
  requestAnimationFrame(drawTriangle.bind(this));
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var centerX = this.canv.width / 2;
  var centerY = this.canv.height / 4;
  this.phase += 0.005 * tau;

  if (this.first == 1) {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canv.width, this.canv.height);
  }
  this.ctx.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0; i <= this.sides; i++) {
    this.ctx[i ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](
      centerX + this.size * Math.cos(this.phase + i / this.sides * tau),
      centerY + this.size * Math.sin(this.phase + i / this.sides * tau)
    );
  }
  this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#dda36b';
  this.ctx.stroke();
  this.size--;
}

var collection = [];

var triangle1 = new Triangle(canvas, context, 3, 1);
triangle1.draw();

var i = 0;

function nextFrame() {
  if (i < 1000) {
    collection[i] = new Triangle(canvas, context, 3, 0);
    collection[i].draw();
    i++;
    setTimeout(nextFrame, 500);
  }
}
setTimeout(nextFrame, 0);
```

```css
.mycanvas {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #19191b
}
.mydiv {
   position:absolute;
   left:100px;
   top:30px;
   opacity:0.5;
   background-color: rgb(100, 100, 200);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
      <canvas class="mycanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="mydiv">
       Hello World!
    </div>
</div>
```